# How Yii control its cronjobs in Linux server?

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii, cron

I am developing a Yii application which has a cron-job running along with. Everything is OK, cron job run successfully. But on Ubuntu when I tried to list all crontabs created by my account (the account used to login to server) as well as www-data (the one represent for Apache), I cannot find anything useful. They all told me that **no crontab for `that_user`**. How can I find the list of those crontabs and kill them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you using VDS then you can run this commands:

`crontab -l` - show list of all cronjobs for current user

`crontab -e` - edit list cronjobs for current user

If you have only FTP access, then crontab setup located in DirectAdmin panel (or other server control panel)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu connect your sever with terminal and run command `crontab -e` using it you will see and edit or delete all your cron-job.